# if else condition is not run properlly

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code and I am unable to run my simple condition. I have used all the ways but it's not working. As I wanted that if count is available then show count and if not then echo 0 in . I know it is simple but I am stuck on it.

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "usman";

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);
$result = $dbh->query(
    "SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt
        FROM ams
        where empid= {$_SESSION['sess_user_id']}
        GROUP BY leavetype
        HAVING leavetype = 'Annual'"
);

if (!$result) {
    echo "<td>";
    echo 0;
    echo "</td>";
} else {
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        echo "<td>" . $row['cnt'] . "</td>";
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: where is `session_start()`?

Comment: your missing a `}` for the else. you only have the `}` for your for loop

Answer (score 1):

## Your solution

```
<?php
session_start();

$hostname = "localhost";  
$username = "root";  
$password = "";  
$db = "usman";  

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);  
$result = $dbh->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM ams where empid= {$_SESSION['sess_user_id']} GROUP BY leavetype HAVING leavetype = 'Annual'");

if (!$result) {
    echo "<td>" . 0 . "</td>";
} else {
    foreach($result as $row) {
        echo "<td>" . $row['cnt'] . "</td>";  
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

## Explanation

It appears you are missing a `}` at the end of your if-else loop. Additionally, if you are using `$_SESSION` super-global variables, you need to invoke `session_start()` first.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: While using if else conditions from the `Query` it is advisable to `echo` the `Query` and exit the operations after that line so that we can see the query that we have to execute in the browser and you can `navigate` to `phpmyadmin` and place the query in `SQL` and click on `GO`. So that this is one of the very easy method to find whether the query runs or not.

**Missing Condions:**

1. Session Start is missing in the file
2. Close brace for the loops opened is missing

**General Instruction:**
Sometimes if the query is not executing properly also the result of the query will return `FALSE` so that it is adviced to take the count of the rows after tht query is executed and perform the operations after that.

Your Correct Code look like:

```
<?php
session_start();
$hostname = "localhost";  
$username = "root";  
$password = "";  
$db = "usman";  
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);  
$result = $dbh->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM ams where empid='".$_SESSION['sess_user_id']."' GROUP BY leavetype HAVING leavetype = 'Annual'");
$count = $result->num_rows;
if($count==0)
{
    echo "<td>" . 0 . "</td>";  
}
 else {
    foreach($result as $row) {
        echo "<td>" . $row['cnt'] . "</td>";  
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

If you check the condition with the count of the query executed you can attain your solution in a better way and you can understand very easy so that it avoids confusion if you look at the code some years back too.